# django rest framework key error request in self.context

Tags: serialization, django-rest-framework

I am getting the key error request even when I pass request to the serializer.
My code looks like below:
I have also tried `self.context.get('request')` but that also isn't working.
I want to set the `agentId` through views as current `user.id` instead of taking it manually through the html form that the api renders.

serializers.py

```
class LoanAgentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    agentId = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Loan
        fields='__all__'
        read_only_fields=['agentId','state']
    
    def get_agentId(self,obj):
        agentId = self.context["request"].user.id
        return agentId
```

views.py

```
class AgentLoanView(APIView):
    permission_classes=(IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class=LoanAgentSerializer
    def post(self,request):
            user=request.user
            if user.role==2:
                serializer=self.serializer_class(data=request.data,context={'request':request})
                valid=serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

                if valid:
                    serializer.save()
                    status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK
                    response = {
                    'success': True,
                    'status_code': status_code,
                    'message': 'Successfully created loan request',
                    'loan': serializer.data,
                    
                    

                }
                    return Response(response,status=status_code)
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

models.py

```
class Loan(models.Model):
    STATES=[
        ('New', 'New'),
        ('Approved', 'Approved'),
        ('Rejected', 'Rejected'),

    ]
    customerId=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='customer')
    agentId=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='agent')
    state=models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=STATES,default='New')
    amount_required = models.IntegerField()
    tenure=models.IntegerField()
    interest=models.FloatField()
```

```
Internal Server Error: /loanManagement/auth/agent/loan
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\projects\loan\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\projects\loan\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\projects\loan\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\projects\loan\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\projects\loan\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "D:\projects\loan\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "D:\projects\loan\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "D:\projects\loan\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\projects\loan\loanManagement\views.py", line 178, in get
    'loans': serializer.data,
  File "D:\projects\loan\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 745, in data
    ret = super().data
  File "D:\projects\loan\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 246, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "D:\projects\loan\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 663, in to_representation
    return [
  File "D:\projects\loan\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 664, in <listcomp>
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
  File "D:\projects\loan\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 515, in to_representation
    ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
  File "D:\projects\loan\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py", line 1870, in to_representation
    return method(value)
  File "D:\projects\loan\loanManagement\serializers.py", line 88, in get_agentId
    agentId = self.context["request"].user.id
KeyError: 'request'
```